# Three20 Library Cannot find its own headers Xcode iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, three20

`#import "Three20/Three20.h"` Fails. Go download it and build a sample app. If that works, then make a new app from the templates provided, then watch as it fails spectacularly to find the right HEADER_SEARCH_PATH.

1) I've gone to the info page for the TARGET and not the PROJECT (Well, I tried both) and tried a bunch of different paths for the HEADER_SEARCH_PATH field.

2) I've tried dragging and dropping the dependent files from the finder and COPYING or just referencing both fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [this](http://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/Articles/AboutModules.mdown).  It is an article about the (very) recent three20 changes that you are having troubles with.  Pay attention to the sections `Imports` and `Migrating to the New Three20`.

Comment: yeah, it is 2 years old. The "new" three20 is no longer new